# Writing to a text file causing unnecessary line breaks

Tags: vb.net, ping

So I'm currently pinging a smtp to check if the IP is working or not and then writing to a text file with my findings, everything is working a part from one thing. When it writes to the text file its doing loads and loads of line breaks which I don’t want/need.

```
                    IO.File.AppendAllText(SummaryfilePath, Now.ToLongTimeString & " - " & URL + vbNewLine)

                    Dim request As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient(URL)
                    Dim address As String()

                    address = request.Host.Split(":")
                    request.Host = address(1)
                    request.Host = request.Host.TrimStart("/")

                    Dim tcpClient As New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient()

                    tcpClient.Connect(request.Host, request.Port)
                    Try
                        Dim networkStream As Sockets.NetworkStream = tcpClient.GetStream()
                        If networkStream.CanWrite And networkStream.CanRead Then
                            ' Do a simple write.
                            Dim sendBytes As [Byte]() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Is anybody there?")
                            networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)
                            ' Read the NetworkStream into a byte buffer.
                            Dim bytes(tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
                            networkStream.Read(bytes, 0, CInt(tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize))
                            ' Output the data received from the host to the console.
                            Dim returndata As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)

                            IO.File.AppendAllText(SummaryfilePath, Now.ToLongTimeString & " - " & returndata & vbNewLine & vbNewLine)

                            'Using sw As StreamWriter = File.AppendText(SummaryfilePath)
                            '    sw.WriteLine(Now.ToLongTimeString & " - " & returndata & vbNewLine & vbNewLine)
                            '    sw.WriteLine("")
                            'End Using

                        Else
                            If Not networkStream.CanRead Then
                                Console.WriteLine("cannot not write data to this stream")
                                tcpClient.Close()
                            Else
                                If Not networkStream.CanWrite Then
                                    Console.WriteLine("cannot read data from this stream")
                                    tcpClient.Close()
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        IO.File.AppendAllText(SummaryfilePath, Now.ToLongTimeString & " - ERROR! " & ex.Message + vbNewLine & vbNewLine)
                    End Try

                End If
```

this is the line of code which writes to the text file and after that it does at least 50/60 line breaks in the text file before doing the next ping.

```
                            IO.File.AppendAllText(SummaryfilePath, Now.ToLongTimeString & " - " & returndata & vbNewLine & vbNewLine)
```

I have tried using a streamwriter as well but it does the same thing. I have looked at what returndata to see if it's coming back with millions of like breaks, which it is not. Any help would be amazing.

Comment: You know that `vbNewLine` is adding line break, right?

Comment: @Nadeem_MK - Yeah I know that, and its suppose to be adding 2 lines. When I open up the text file I have about 50/60. Removing VbNewLine does not fix this problem.

Comment: Check the docs about Encoding.ASCII.GetString https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/744y86tc(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

How about using something a little simpler?

```
If My.Computer.Network.Ping("ftp://ftp.drivehq.com/") Then
     Dim request As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.drivehq.com/file.txt"), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)
     request.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "password")
     request.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile

     Dim file() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("c:\file.txt")

     Dim strz As System.IO.Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
     strz.Write(file, 0, file.Length)
     strz.Close()
     strz.Dispose()
Else
     MsgBox("Can't connect to FTP server")
End IF
```

And then just write your data to **c:\file.txt** Of course it isn't recommended to use the base of the **C:\ drive**